# OSMDroid Tabbed Activity Swipe

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, osmdroid

I'm creating a tabbed Android project that uses OSMDroid to display a map in one of the fragments and some other information in some other fragment (in another tab).

The way you move from tab to tab is by swiping left or right or by pressing on the tab buttons at the top of the application.

However, when you want to scroll the map that is contained in the first fragment to the left, for example (to the West), then you will actually swipe to the other tab instead of scrolling the map.

Does anybody know how can I "tell" my application that, when I scroll on the map, I actually want the map to scroll and not the application to swipe to another tab? I've seen this implementation in other apps, where you can swipe to another tab if you swipe at the edge of the screen, but if you swipe somewhere in the middle (or more precisely said, "not at the edge of the screen") you will scroll the map that's in that tab, and not go to another tab.

Any ideas on how to make this work?